# Push values from web server to client every 20ms (Java MVC)

Tags: java, model-view-controller, servlets

I am new to Java. I am trying to write something on lines of MVC where my web server has a java method that reads a text file one row at a time every 20 milliseconds and I want to send (/push) this value to client every 20 milliseconds (that is at the same instant as the new row is read from CSV). 
I have read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29
But being very new to all this could not understand much. How push/pull/streaming works and what to use here. Moreover if I should be pulling or pushing values here. I think I should push else server will be clogged by so many pull requests every 20ms. 
Please suggest. Any piece of code will be a great great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot push data from Web server to client/browser as client machines firewall will block any kind of connection you try to make with machine. Browser has always need to pull it from server.

You can virtually achieve this by using reverse ajax using long lived HTTP connection from Javascript/Ajax

Please refer to following link for the example

http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/03/22/developing-applications-using-reverse-ajax.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. My primary concern in update every 20 millisecond. :(

Answer (score 1):

Push would seem to be the best answer here, though you may have some issues getting everything to work on a 20ms round-trip without falling behind, unless this is all going to work on a local network.

The currently-emerging state of the art for push seems to be HTML5 WebSockets.
If you can ensure use of the latest web browsers that have support for it, I would suggest going with that.

[Here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/creating-websocket-chat) is an example of building a simple WebSocket app.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the reply. Web sockets sounds exciting but the only small concern will be setting is up differently for different web servers. But it helps. Can you please throw some light over http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/03/22/developing-applications-using-reverse-ajax.html also. I mean what do you think about it.

Comment: And http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/websockets-or-comet-or-both-whats-supported-in-the-java-ee-land/  this says that Tomcat and WebSphere both do not support comet or websockets  .. And I need the web app to work on both of these :'(

Comment: @user969107 The first article is over 5 years old, so a little bit out of date. The table in the second article lists Tomcat 7 as supporting both Comet and WebSockets - which I'm sure is correct. It looks like you may be out of luck with WebSphere, though. If you really need lowest-common-denominator, try Comet, specifically the Atmosphere implementation, as I believe it falls back to polling when 'real' Comet is not supported. As far as I know JMS is not a good solution for the web browser client.

Comment: Thanks a lot GreyBeardedGeek... It looks like I finally found what I wanted ... Please have a look .. you may find it fascinating too .. (in case you haven't came this across before :) ) ... http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/ .... Please comment what do you think about this .. yes this is a single way communication .. but good enough for my purpose ..

Comment: No real magic there, other than a formal spec. It's still client-side polling. And I suspect that it's going to be difficult to impossible to get 20ms updates that way, but good luck!

Comment: Why do you think 20ms updates will be difficult and how will it be more feasible using web sockets ?

Comment: It depends on the throughput / latency of your network. On a local network you may be fine. On the public internet, it seems to me that consistently getting that kind of network performance is unlikely at best. Web Sockets, if directly supported, rather than emulated, will at least keep a socket open for the life of the client. Anything that does low-level polling will need to set up and tear down a connection for each poll.